# How to delete row in Google Sheet if "Column A" cell CONTAINS given text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to implement a Google Script so that if any cell in column A INCLUDES any specified text, then it will delete the entire row. Here is what i'm working with...

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change to your own
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var row in values)
    if (values[row][0] == 'glass')
      s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);

    else if (values[row][0] == 'Glass')
      s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);

};
```

I am going to include multiple different criteria to clean my spreadsheet for me. Some of the rows might include "auto glass", "autoglass", "Glass repair", "Glass Doctor", "Glass Smith" Etc...

Currently, this code deletes the rows where the column A cell is "Glass" or "glass".

PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must delete rows from the end.  If you start at the beginning, and delete a row, all the rows below that row will now be out of sync with the order of the values in the array.  After the first row is deleted, all the other rows that get deleted will probably be the wrong row, unless you adjusted the code for the row number.  Try using this code:

```
function cleanRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var colA_Vals = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  var i = 0,
      j = 0,
      thisVal,
      chkVal,
      arrayValsToChk = ['glass'];

  for (i=colA_Vals.length;i>0;i-=1) {
    thisVal = colA_Vals[i-1][0];
    //Logger.log('i: ' + i);

    for (j=0;j<arrayValsToChk.length;j+=1) {
      chkVal = arrayValsToChk[j].toLowerCase() //Change to all lower case;

      if (thisVal.indexOf(chkVal) !== -1) {
        ss.deleteRow(i);
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Note the array for all the values to check for.  Add new values to the array to check for other values.

Comment: Sandy, it's almost there. I see what you did, however, it's still not working as I need it to. It is deleting the rows that match exactly the data specified in the array, but I need it to delete any rows that include those keywords. For example, some of the values include "The glass guy" "Glass Doctor" "Auto glass repair" etc. I need it to delete ANYTHING that includes the word "glass". I'm sorting through about 1500 rows and need to automate the clean-up.

Comment: I made some changes to the code which will hopefully work for you.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 2):

Sandy is of course correct in how to delete rows. That is probably the most important point. I also suggest changing the strings to lower case so you just have to do one test. Try this:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change to your own
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=values.length;i>0;i-=1){
     var lcVal=values[i-1][0].toLowerCase() //Change to all lower case
     var index = lcVal.indexOf("glass"); //now you only have to check for  contains "glass"
     if (lcVal.indexOf("glass") > -1){
     s.deleteRow(i)};
  }}
```