# How to delete rows if contains a string only in a specific column with spreadsheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet with my sheet called "Products":
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AflG3VgCFdqz1dRbP0JwGBrc5xXL9kwRBk13yEpekTM/edit#gid=1671517193

I find the initial script here:
// [How to delete row in Google Sheet if "Column A" cell CONTAINS given text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643421/how-to-delete-row-in-google-sheet-if-column-a-cell-contains-given-text)

Column F contains my categories, but I want to delete all rows with 
 the if contain the next strings:
" CD"
"MP3"
"Todos"

I hope if possible do with these conditions:
1. Remove if contains the whole of part of the string. For example, if in the column you see: 
"COMPANY / Income / CD / in"
the script will delete because the cell contains " CD"

2. Ignore the letter case. For example, all of these will delete:
   " CD"
   " cd"
   " cD"

Here, my code is not working, because delete some correct rows. The Error is in the function findStringAndDeleteRow.

```
var sheetName = "Products"; 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);


function onOpen(){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
    .createMenu('COMPANY')
    .addItem('Products Cleaner Data', 'findStringAndDeleteRow')
    .addToUi();
  }

function findStringAndDeleteRow() {
  findStringAndDeleteRow_001();
  findStringAndDeleteRow_002();
  findStringAndDeleteRow_003();


}

function findStringAndDeleteRow_001() {
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=values.length;i>0;i-=1){
     var lcVal=values[i-1][5].toLowerCase() //Change to all lower case
     var index = lcVal.indexOf(" cd"); //now you only have to check for  contains "glass"
     if (lcVal.indexOf(" cd") > -1){
     sheet.deleteRow(i)};
  }
}
function findStringAndDeleteRow_002() {
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=values.length;i>0;i-=1){
     var lcVal=values[i-1][5].toLowerCase() //Change to all lower case
     var index = lcVal.indexOf("mp3"); //now you only have to check for  contains "glass"
     if (lcVal.indexOf("mp3") > -1){
     sheet.deleteRow(i)};
  }
}
function findStringAndDeleteRow_003() {
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i=values.length;i>0;i-=1){
     var lcVal=values[i-1][5].toLowerCase() //Change to all lower case
     var index = lcVal.indexOf("todos"); //now you only have to check for  contains "glass"
     if (lcVal.indexOf("todos") > -1){
     sheet.deleteRow(i)};
  }
}
```

I expect delete the rows contain any string like
" CD"
"MP3"
"Todos"

In RED colors you can see the columns need be remove.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You said column F contains categories but actually it appears to be E.

Comment: I am very sorry, its true, is working. When I try with a huge data and my others functions, start to fail. Sorry I will try to double check, before post i expend I lot of hours testing :) thanks for check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full working code I tested linking it to a copy of your Spreadsheet. I used the [`deleteCells()` function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#deletecellsshiftdimension) which will delete the first 7 columns of each row that makes the match.

```
var sheetName = "Products"; 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);

function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .createMenu('COMPANY')
  .addItem('Products Cleaner Data', 'findAndDelete')
  .addToUi();
}

function findAndDelete() {
  var findArray = ["CD","MP3","TODOS"];
  var rowsDelete = [];
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 5, sheet.getLastRow()-1 ,1).getValues();

  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var cell = data[i][0].toUpperCase(); 
    var cellArray = cell.split(" / ");  
    Logger.log(cellArray);

    for (var j=0; j<cellArray.length; j++) {
      var value = cellArray[j];

      if(findArray.indexOf(value) != -1) {
        Logger.log(value);
        rowsDelete.unshift(2 + i);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  for(i=0; i<rowsDelete.length ; i++) {
    var position = sheet.getRange(rowsDelete[i], 1, 1, 7);
    position.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }   
}
```

[See the video explanation](https://youtu.be/EwxoVb9LgFY)

[Google SpreadSheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AflG3VgCFdqz1dRbP0JwGBrc5xXL9kwRBk13yEpekTM/edit#gid=1671517193)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findAndDelete(findArray,searchCol) {
  var findArray=findArray||["CD","MP3","Todos"];//default
  var searchCol=searchCol||"categories";//default
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet177');
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var cObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<hA.length;i++) {
    cObj[String(hA[i]).toLowerCase()]=i+1;
  }
  var srg=sh.getRange(2,cObj[searchCol.toLowerCase()],sh.getLastRow()-1,1);
  for(var i=0;i<findArray.length;i++) {
    var f=srg.createTextFinder(String(findArray[i])).matchCase(true).findAll();
    var d=0;
    if(f.length>0) {
      for(var j=0;j<f.length;j++) {
        sh.deleteRow(f[j].getRow()-d++);
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: amazing! go very fast :) but I get the next error: Service error: Spreadsheets (line 25, file "Code") 
the line 25 is this: 
var f=srg.createTextFinder(String(findArray[i])).matchCase(true).findAll();

Comment: It works for me on your linked spreadsheet data with no errors.

Comment: I added 2 columns to count the rows, before and after run the script. Like you can see you get a error. the sheet has Edit permission you can test yourself.
Note one of the string is " CD" not "CD"

Comment: Hi Cooper, finally the script works with the Andres script above. But also thanks a lot for help me :)